# Definition of string manipulation in Python

Tags: python, string, terminology

What does "string manipulation" mean in Python? Is every action on strings (like concatenation) kind of manipulation?

Or, in the below example, is adding backslash n in the string a string manipulation?

```
"Name: Abbas\nSex: Male"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That's a broad term and we may need more context to say. Its not like its in the Dictionary of Computer Science (if there is such a thing). I'd guess that anything that changes a string or selects part of a string (in python's case, both of these would create new strings) is manipulation.

Comment: Strings in Python can't be manipulated directly, you have to replace one string with a different one.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly just the plain English definition, if you take an existing string, and you manipulate it to make new strings, that's string manipulation. Any programmatic operation that starts with one (or more) strings and produces a (logically, if not actually) new string is a form of a string manipulation. Slicing, concatenation, repeating, interpolation, formatting, etc. are all forms of string manipulation. Reading strings from the user or a file unmodified, passing around strings without changing them, or printing existing strings is not string manipulation (you're making new strings or using existing strings without creating new mutated versions of them; no "manipulation" is going on).

For the specific case of `"Name: Abbas\nSex: Male"`, the string literal alone is not string *manipulation*, it's just a string literal that happens to have an escape sequence in it. If you originally had `"Name: Abbas"` and `"Sex: Male"` and stitched them together with a `"\n"` at runtime to make `"Name: Abbas\nSex: Male"`, that would be string manipulation.